# Fullcalendar 4 Day View

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am using jQuery Full Calendar and stuck with a view. I want a 4 day view just like Google calendar. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With versions 2.2.5+ of Full Calendar this type of view customization is a lot easier.

Adding something like this to your calendars uiConfig should now do this trick.

```
views: {
  agendaFourDay: {
    type: 'agenda',
    duration: { days: 4 },
    buttonText: '4 day'
  },
  defaultView: 'agendaFourDay'
}
```

You can get more information on this from the document page on [Custom Views](http://fullcalendar.io/docs/views/Custom_Views/).

Answer (score 0):

Fullcalendar only have 3 views, Month, Week and Day view acctualy 5 agendaWeek + agendaDay, for example in the week view if you have this setting [here](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/display/weekends/) and set it to false, your week view will only display the common work days 5 days.

Comment: Thanks for the Reply Henrique , But may be you have misunderstood the question , what I mean is In my calendar I want to define a range of 4 days. Just like Google Calendar has. Please see that once, And I am still stucked :( , Thanks anyways

Comment: Yes i understood, the thing is the most close thing you have in Fullcalendar with the 4 day view is the 5 day view with no weekends. Sry buddy

Answer (score 0):

I was able to sort-of get this to work by re-rendering the calendar every time the view changes. This obviously isn't ideal, but it gets the job done (for me) for now.

I'm working with multiple calendars on the same page, so I made this function to handle the rendering of each calendar.

```js
var calendarInit = function(calendar, start, defaultView){

    $('#' + calendar).fullCalendar('destroy')

    var dayNumber = start.getDay();
    var hiddenDays = []
    if (defaultView === 'agendaWeek'){
        dayNumber = dayNumber + 3
        if (dayNumber > 6) {
            dayNumber = dayNumber - 7
        }
        for (var i=0;i<3;i++) {
            dayNumber++
            if (dayNumber > 6) {
                dayNumber = dayNumber - 7
            }
            hiddenDays.push(dayNumber)
        }
    }


    var data = {
        header: {
            left: 'prev,next today',
            center: 'title',
            right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
        },
        defaultView: defaultView,
        editable: true,
        durationEditable: false,
        allDaySlot: false,
        events: '/' + calendar + '.json',
        firstDay: dayNumber,
        hiddenDays: hiddenDays,
        date: start.getDate(),
        month: start.getMonth()
    }


    $('#' + calendar).fullCalendar(data)


    var currentDate = $('#' + calendar).fullCalendar( 'getDate' )

    if (defaultView === 'agendaWeek'){
        $('.fc-button-next, .fc-button-prev, .fc-button-month').addClass('ignore')

        $('#' + calendar + ' .fc-button-next').click(function() {
            currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate()+4);
            calendarInit(calendar, isMaster, currentDate, defaultView)
        })
        $('#' + calendar + ' .fc-button-prev').click(function() {
            currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate()-4);
            calendarInit(calendar, isMaster, currentDate, defaultView)
        })
        $('.fc-button-month').click(function() {
            calendarInit(calendar, isMaster, start, 'month')
        })
    }

    $('.fc-button-agendaWeek').click(function() {
        calendarInit(calendar, isMaster, currentDate, 'agendaWeek')
    })
    $('.fc-button-agendaDay').click(function() {
        calendarInit(calendar, isMaster, currentDate, 'agendaDay')
    })

}
//render the initial calendar
calendarInit('confirmed', true, date, 'agendaWeek')
```

I also had to edit the fullcalendar.js source at line 806 to get the calendar to ignore button clicks if the calendar is going to re-render:

```js
.click(function() {
    if (!button.hasClass(tm + '-state-disabled') && !button.hasClass('ignore')) {
        buttonClick();
    }
})
```

This is all very hacky, and hopefully someone has recommended edits or an alternative solution. I'm working on this for a client, so I'll come back with any edits or further comments I end up adding.